# Perl's `kill` is using `$! == Errno::EINTR` unexpectedly

Tags: perl, kill, signals, fork

I wrote a network daemon that forks off children to handle TCP connections.
On `SIGINT` the main process triggers a `kill` for each child in order to clean up and to collect some final statistics.

In almost all cases that works fine, and the child processes terminate really fast.
However occasionally a child process just refuses to die within a short timeout (like 5 seconds).

I had no idea what happened then, so I added some verbose output to diagnose that case.
I found out that using `netcat` to open a connection, then suspending that `netcat` process, *sometimes* causes the effect.

When I was able to reproduce the effect the debug output was:

```text
REST-server(cleanup_queue): deleting children
REST-server(cleanup_queue): deleting PID 23344 handling localhost:48114
child_delete: Killing child 23344
child_delete: killed child with PID 23344
(r1, r2) = (1, Interrupted system call)
_limited_wait(PID 23344 terminated): waiting up to 5 seconds for condition
_limited_wait(PID 23344 terminated): waiting 0.02 (of 5 remaining) seconds
(r1, r2) = (1, Interrupted system call)
_limited_wait(PID 23344 terminated): waiting 0.04 (of 4.98 remaining) seconds
(r1, r2) = (1, Interrupted system call)
_limited_wait(PID 23344 terminated): waiting 0.08 (of 4.94 remaining) seconds
(r1, r2) = (1, Interrupted system call)
_limited_wait(PID 23344 terminated): waiting 0.16 (of 4.86 remaining) seconds
(r1, r2) = (1, Interrupted system call)
_limited_wait(PID 23344 terminated): waiting 0.32 (of 4.7 remaining) seconds
(r1, r2) = (1, Interrupted system call)
_limited_wait(PID 23344 terminated): waiting 0.64 (of 4.38 remaining) seconds
(r1, r2) = (1, Interrupted system call)
_limited_wait(PID 23344 terminated): waiting 1.28 (of 3.74 remaining) seconds
(r1, r2) = (1, Interrupted system call)
_limited_wait(PID 23344 terminated): waiting 2.46 (of 2.46 remaining) seconds
(r1, r2) = (1, Interrupted system call)
child_delete: PID 23344 refused to terminate within 5s
failed to delete child PID 23344
```

The "condition" to wait for in that case was the result of this closure:

```perl
sub {
    my $r1 = kill(0, $child_pid);
    my $r2 = $!;
    print "(r1, r2) = ($r1, $r2)\n";
    $r1 != 1 && $r2 == Errno::ESRCH;
}
```

So the expected outcome would be that the main process is unable to "kill" the PID, because it does no longer exist (and not because of a "permission denied").

However for some reasons I get an "Interrupted system call" repeatedly.

The main process uses signal handlers like this:

```perl
$SIG{'INT'} = $SIG{'TERM'} = sub ($) {
    my $signal = 'SIG' . $_[0];
    my $me = "signal handler[$$, $signal]";

    print "$me: cleaning up\n"
        if ($verbose > 0);
    cleanup();
    print "$me: executing default action\n"
        if ($verbose > 1);
    $SIG{$_[0]} = 'DEFAULT';
    kill($_[0], $$);                    # execute default action
};
```

And when forking a child process, I reset the signal handlers like this:

```perl
sub child_create($)
{
    my ($child) = @_;
    my $pid;

    reaper(0);                          # disable for the child
    if ($pid = fork()) {                # parent
        reaper(1);                      # enable for the parent
    } elsif (defined($pid)) {           # child
        my ($child_fun, @child_param) = @$child;
        my $ret;

        # prevent double-cleanup
        $SIG{'INT'} = $SIG{'TERM'} = $SIG{'__DIE__'} = 'DEFAULT';
        $ret = $child_fun->(@child_param);
        exit($ret);                     # avoid returning from function call
    } else {                            # error
        print STDERR "child_create: fork(): $!\n";
    }
    return $pid;
}
```

The `reaper()` just handles `SIGCHLD`.

What could cause the effect seen?
The child processes basically do a `while (defined(my $req = $conn->get_request)) {...}` (using `HTTP::Daemon`), so they should be waiting for input in the `netcat` case.

### Additional info

Just in case it might matter: OS is SLES12 SP5 (using Perl 5.18.2) running on VMware.

The code in the main server loop looks like this:

```perl
while (defined(my $conn = $daemon->accept) || $! == Errno::EINTR) {
    my $errno = $!;

    if ($quit_flag != 0) {
        last;
    }
    if ($errno == Errno::EINTR) {
        next;
    }
    #... handle $req->uri->path()
}
```